# unnecessary price extension received from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting unnecessary price length from my item. for an example if the price is `12.99` I will get `12.9899997711`

my database looks something like below with over 800 items

**product table**

```
ppid         name             dec
1             shoes           black shoes
2             hat              red hat
```

**item_product table**

my price is `type` `float(5,2)`

```
Item_ID        ppid             price
1               1                12.99
2               2                10.00
```

**PHP/HTML**
This is how I show my price

```
<?php
        dbconnection(); 
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, Price FROM item_product WHERE ppid=:id LIMIT 1");
        $stmt2->bindParam('id',$id);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $rows2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        foreach ($rows2 as $row2) {
            if ($i == 0) {  
            echo '<td>Price:</td>';
                echo '<td name="pricetag" class="pricetag" id="pricetag">&pound;'.$row2['Price'].'</td>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

**Summary**
How can I get it to show `.99` and `.00` for any item that have any of those at the end.

Comment: This may help http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency - use decimal types for money.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your price field is probably defined as some sort of floating point type, which will not accurately save decimal numbers.  For currencies, you want to save the exact amount, so use the `DECIMAL` data type to define the column.

Comment: Thanks I will use decimal.